# Actionscript3 shooter game error 1009 and 2009

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Good day everyone! I'm Jeremy, a college student. I'm working on a shooter game that has story and up to 3 levels (this is our finals that is due in 2 days). I know that I must know this stuff bcoz of school, but honestly I dont. And I'm really not good with actionscript 3 so I really need ur help guys. I know that this problem has been all over the net. But I still don't know how to solve the Error Code 1009 and 2007..

So this is my code for frame4:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;


stop();

var container:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
addChild(container);



//move the spaceship using our mouse

function controlSpaceShip(event:Event):void 
{

 shipMC.x = stage.mouseX;
 Mouse.hide();

}

stop();
var score:int = 0;

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, controlSpaceShip);


//shoot bullets when we left click on the mouse
function shootBullet(event:MouseEvent):void 
{

    var thebullet:MovieClip = new bullet(); //calls the bullet symbol from the library

    //positions the bullet at the position of your ship
    thebullet.x = shipMC.x + 30;
    thebullet.y = shipMC.y + 20; 

    //we add the bullet onto the stage
    container.addChild(thebullet);


}

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, shootBullet);

//when bullet hits the enemy1
function hitEnemy(event:Event):void {

    if (container.hitTestObject(enemy1)) {

        enemy1.alpha = 0;
        score = score + 5;
        txtScore.text = (score).toString();
    }

}

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, hitEnemy); 


//when bullet hits the enemy2
function hitEnemy2(event:Event):void {

    if (container.hitTestObject(enemy2)) {

        enemy2.alpha = 0;
        score = score + 5;
        txtScore.text = (score).toString();
    }

}

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, hitEnemy2); 

//when bullet hits the enemy3
function hitEnemy3(event:Event):void {

    if (container.hitTestObject(enemy3)) {

        enemy3.alpha = 0;
        score = score + 5;
        txtScore.text = (score).toString();
    }

}

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, hitEnemy3); 

//when bullet hits the enemy4
function hitEnemy4(event:Event):void {

    if (container.hitTestObject(enemy4)) {

        enemy4.alpha = 0;
        score = score + 5;
        txtScore.text = (score).toString();
    }

}

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, hitEnemy4); 

//when bullet hits the enemy5
function hitEnemy5(event:Event):void {

    if (container.hitTestObject(enemy5)) {

        enemy5.alpha = 0;
        score = score + 5;
        txtScore.text = (score).toString();
    }

}

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, hitEnemy5); 

//when bullet hits the enemy6
function hitEnemy6(event:Event):void {

    if (container.hitTestObject(enemy6)) {

        enemy6.alpha = 0;
        score = score + 5;
        txtScore.text = (score).toString();
    }
    if (txtScore.text == (150).toString())
    {
        gotoAndStop(5);
    }

}

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, hitEnemy6); 


//move the enemies vertically

function moveEnemies(event:Event):void {


    //ENEMY 1
    enemy1.y += 8; //increment the y location of my enemy 6 pixels

    if (enemy1.y > 600) { //if my enemy is outside the stage

        enemy1.y = 0; //place it back on the stage
        enemy1.x = Math.random() * 550; //randomize its horizontal location
    }


    //ENEMY 2
    enemy2.y += 4; //increment the y location of my enemy 3 pixels

    if (enemy2.y > 600) { //if my enemy is outside the stage

        enemy2.y = 0; //place it back on the stage
        enemy2.x = Math.random() * 550; //randomize its horizontal location
    }


    //ENEMY 3
    enemy3.y += 3; //increment the y location of my enemy 3 pixels

    if (enemy3.y > 600) { //if my enemy is outside the stage

        enemy3.y = 0; //place it back on the stage
        enemy3.x = Math.random() * 550; //randomize its horizontal location
    }


    //ENEMY 4
    enemy4.y += 4; //increment the y location of my enemy 3 pixels

    if (enemy4.y > 600) { //if my enemy is outside the stage

        enemy4.y = 0; //place it back on the stage
        enemy4.x = Math.random() * 550; //randomize its horizontal location
    }


    //ENEMY 5
    enemy5.y += 4; //increment the y location of my enemy 3 pixels

    if (enemy5.y > 600) { //if my enemy is outside the stage

        enemy5.y = 0; //place it back on the stage
        enemy5.x = Math.random() * 550; //randomize its horizontal location
    }


    //ENEMY 6
    enemy6.y += 4; //increment the y location of my enemy 3 pixels

    if (enemy6.y > 600) { //if my enemy is outside the stage

        enemy6.y = 0; //place it back on the stage
        enemy6.x = Math.random() * 550; //randomize its horizontal location
    }
}

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveEnemies);
```

so after killing all 6 enemies and scoring at least 150, I want the frame to jump to frame5(success) while frame 5 has the button to click going to frame6(story and goes to level2)..

and here's the error that keeps on going and going..

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at finals_interactivegame2_fla::MainTimeline/moveEnemies()
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at finals_interactivegame2_fla::MainTimeline/controlSpaceShip()
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter hitTestObject must be non-null.
    at flash.display::DisplayObject/_hitTest()
    at flash.display::DisplayObject/hitTestObject()
    at finals_interactivegame2_fla::MainTimeline/hitEnemy()
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter hitTestObject must be non-null.
    at flash.display::DisplayObject/_hitTest()
    at flash.display::DisplayObject/hitTestObject()
    at finals_interactivegame2_fla::MainTimeline/hitEnemy2()
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter hitTestObject must be non-null.
    at flash.display::DisplayObject/_hitTest()
    at flash.display::DisplayObject/hitTestObject()
    at finals_interactivegame2_fla::MainTimeline/hitEnemy3()
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter hitTestObject must be non-null.
    at flash.display::DisplayObject/_hitTest()
    at flash.display::DisplayObject/hitTestObject()
    at finals_interactivegame2_fla::MainTimeline/hitEnemy4()
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter hitTestObject must be non-null.
    at flash.display::DisplayObject/_hitTest()
    at flash.display::DisplayObject/hitTestObject()
    at finals_interactivegame2_fla::MainTimeline/hitEnemy5()
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter hitTestObject must be non-null.
    at flash.display::DisplayObject/_hitTest()
    at flash.display::DisplayObject/hitTestObject()
    at finals_interactivegame2_fla::MainTimeline/hitEnemy6()
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at finals_interactivegame2_fla::MainTimeline/moveEnemies()
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at finals_interactivegame2_fla::MainTimeline/controlSpaceShip()
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter hitTestObject must be non-null.
    at flash.display::DisplayObject/_hitTest()
    at flash.display::DisplayObject/hitTestObject()
    at finals_interactivegame2_fla::MainTimeline/hitEnemy()
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter hitTestObject must be non-null.
    at flash.display::DisplayObject/_hitTest()
    at flash.display::DisplayObject/hitTestObject()
    at finals_interactivegame2_fla::MainTimeline/hitEnemy2()
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter hitTestObject must be non-null.
    at flash.display::DisplayObject/_hitTest()
    at flash.display::DisplayObject/hitTestObject()
    at finals_interactivegame2_fla::MainTimeline/hitEnemy3()
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter hitTestObject must be non-null.
    at flash.display::DisplayObject/_hitTest()
    at flash.display::DisplayObject/hitTestObject()
    at finals_interactivegame2_fla::MainTimeline/hitEnemy4()
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter hitTestObject must be non-null.
    at flash.display::DisplayObject/_hitTest()
    at flash.display::DisplayObject/hitTestObject()
    at finals_interactivegame2_fla::MainTimeline/hitEnemy5()
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter hitTestObject must be non-null.
    at flash.display::DisplayObject/_hitTest()
    at flash.display::DisplayObject/hitTestObject()
    at finals_interactivegame2_fla::MainTimeline/hitEnemy6()
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at finals_interactivegame2_fla::MainTimeline/moveEnemies()
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at finals_interactivegame2_fla::MainTimeline/controlSpaceShip()
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter hitTestObject must be non-null.
    at flash.display::DisplayObject/_hitTest()
    at flash.display::DisplayObject/hitTestObject()
    at finals_interactivegame2_fla::MainTimeline/hitEnemy()
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter hitTestObject must be non-null.
    at flash.display::DisplayObject/_hitTest()
    at flash.display::DisplayObject/hitTestObject()
    at finals_interactivegame2_fla::MainTimeline/hitEnemy2()
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter hitTestObject must be non-null.
    at flash.display::DisplayObject/_hitTest()
    at flash.display::DisplayObject/hitTestObject()
    at finals_interactivegame2_fla::MainTimeline/hitEnemy3()
```

I hope somebody help me because I don't know what to do anymore. I don't have people to help me. My classmates are not approachable and friendly. and this will be submitted in 2 days. So I don't want to fail. I just hope someone.. someone to help me with my game.

You can check my file at [Actionscript3 shooter game](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=29541694957664463364)
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your adding all these `ENTER_FRAME` listeners,  but then not removing them before you go to the next frame.  So they keep running forever, and they try to reference all your enemy's and container even though those things got unloaded when you changed frames.

To resolve this issue, you need to remove ALL those listeners before you move on to frame 5.

I'd recommend creating a function called `checkGameComplete` or something like that:

```
function checkGameComplete():void {
    if (txtScore.text == (150).toString()){
        stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, hitEnemy6);  //repeat for ALL enter frame listeners
        //rest of the removeEventListeners

        gotoAndStop(5);
    }
}
```

Then call that `checkGameComplete()` on every hitEnemy check.

---

As an aside, make your code less redundant by making ONE hit enemy method, ONE move method, and ONE enter frame listener:

```
stop();
var score:int = 0;
var container:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
addChild(container);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameLoop);  //just the one ENTER FRAME handler
Mouse.hide(); //you only need to call this once, instead of every bullet fire

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, shootBullet);

function shootBullet(event:MouseEvent):void 
{

    var thebullet:MovieClip = new bullet(); //calls the bullet symbol from the library

    //positions the bullet at the position of your ship
    thebullet.x = shipMC.x + 30;
    thebullet.y = shipMC.y + 20; 

    //we add the bullet onto the stage
    container.addChild(thebullet);


}

function gameLoop(event:Event):void {
    if(!shipMC) return;
    shipMC.x = stage.mouseX;
    moveEnemy(enemy1, 8);
    moveEnemy(enemy2, 4);
    moveEnemy(enemy3, 3);
    moveEnemy(enemy4, 4);
    moveEnemy(enemy5, 4);
    moveEnemy(enemy6, 4);

}

function hitEnemyCheck(enemy):void {
    if (container.hitTestObject(enemy)) {
        //enemy.visible = false; //instead of hiding it, move it back up
        enemy.y = -100;

        score = score + 5;
        txtScore.text = (score).toString();
        checkGameComplete();
    }
}

function moveEnemy(enemy, amount):void {
    enemy.y += amount; //increment the y location of my enemy

    if (enemy.y > 600) { //if my enemy is outside the stage 
        enemy.y = 0; //place it back on the stage
        enemy.x = Math.random() * 550; //randomize its horizontal location
    }

    hitEnemyCheck(enemy);
}

function checkGameComplete():void {
    if (txtScore.text == (150).toString()){
        stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameLoop);
        stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, shootBullet); //clean up listeners
        removeChild(container); //get rid of this container you created
        Mouse.show();  //show the mouse again
        gotoAndStop(5);
    }
}
```

---

I also noticed, that on your frame 5 code (and frame 6 code too), you're calling the wrong function on the `next3_btn` click:

```
next3_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,next2Click); // <-- your calling next2Click instead of next3Click
```

Should be:

```
next3_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,next3Click);
```

Comment: Thank  you for this. Now I could go to next frames and eventually make my level 2 and 3. now i'm having a problem, i copied all my working codes for frame 4 and put it on my level 2, adjusted some names and error says conflict exists with definition score/container in namespace internal and Duplicate function definition. :(

Comment: You can't have functions or vars with same name on the same timeline (regardless of frame number).  Your best bet would be to create a class file and put the code in there, or if that is too big of a step at this point in your education, take everything on your frame 4, and convert it to a MovieClip, then put the code on frame 1 of that,  and instead of `gotoAndStop(5)`, do `MovieClip(parent).gotoAndStop(5)` to access the parent timeline.

Comment: everything in frame4 ill make it into movieClip, and where do I exactly put my codes of frame4? thanks for helping much

Comment: You'll want to put a `stop()` on frame 4 still, but put the rest of the code on frame 1 of the new movie clip you made.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. i commend you

Answer (score 0):

In your `hitEnemy6` function and before `gotoAndStop(5)`, you should remove all event listeners that you have already added, to goto to the 5th frame :

```
stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, hitEnemy)
stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, hitEnemy2)
stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, hitEnemy3)
stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, hitEnemy4)
stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, hitEnemy5)
stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, hitEnemy6)
stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveEnemies)
stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, controlSpaceShip)
stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, shootBullet)

gotoAndStop(5)
```

In your `moveEnemies` function, you should verify every time if your `enemy` object is not null using a simple `if` as :

```
if (enemy1) {       
    enemy1.y +=  8
    if (enemy1.y > 600){
        enemy1.y = 0
        enemy1.x = Math.random() * 550
    }
}
```

You should do that for all your `enemy` objects (1 -> 6).

I don't know why you created 6 `Event.ENTER_FRAME`, one for every `enemy` object !? you can simply do :

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, hitEnemy)
function hitEnemy(event:Event):void {   

    if (container.hitTestObject(enemy1)) {

        enemy1.alpha = 0
        score = score + 5
        txtScore.text = (score).toString()

    }

    if (container.hitTestObject(enemy2)) {

        enemy2.alpha = 0
        score = score + 5
        txtScore.text = (score).toString()

    }

    // do the same thing for all your enemy objects ...

}
```

...